# hide/resolve warning messages on my website

Tags: php, web, cakephp-2.0, warnings

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in
 /var/www/humspm/data/www/humspm.com/gettext.php on line 17 CMD:EXIT

can you please help me to resolve this issue
Thanks in adavence

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off notifications in PHP:

```
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>
```

More:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.error-reporting.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp

**I recommend to solve the issue with correct coding instead of just turning off errors and warnings!
For your issue, just check if the file or directory exists before you try to work with the filesystem. (check the PHP manual for file_exists() and is_dir())**

Answer (score 0):

From the CAKEphp manual:

> Error configuration is done inside your application’s
>   `app/Config/core.php` file. You can define a callback to be fired each
>   time your application triggers any PHP error - exceptions are handled
>   Exceptions separately. The callback can be any PHP callable, including
>   an anonymous function. The default error handling configuration looks
>   like:

```
Configure::write('Error', array(
    'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleError',
    'level' => E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED,
    'trace' => true ));
```

> You have 5 built-in options when configuring error handlers:
>
> `handler` - callback - The callback to handle errors. You can set this
>   to any callable type, including anonymous functions.
>
> `level` - int - The
>   level of errors you are interested in capturing. Use the built-in PHP
>   error constants, and bitmasks to select the level of error you are
>   interested in.
>
> `trace` - boolean - Include stack traces for errors in
>   log files. Stack traces will be included in the log after each error.
>   This is helpful for finding where/when errors are being raised.
>
> `consoleHandler` - callback - The callback used to handle errors when
>   running in the console.
>
> If undefined, CakePHP’s default handlers will
>   be used. `ErrorHandler` by default, displays errors when `debug > 0`, and
>   logs errors when `debug = 0`. The type of errors captured in both cases
>   is controlled by `Error.level`. The fatal error handler will be called
>   independent of debug level or `Error.level` configuration, but the
>   result will be different based on debug level.

[Link to manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check what causes this issue,

1. Check folder permission
2. Check whether you have privileges to create a directory inside the specific location.

Still if you want to silence the error

1. You can add `@` in front of `mkdir`
2. You can disable error reporting.

Comment: Nishanth: File location is not there like /var/www/humspm/data/www/humspm.com/gettext.php in my code but it is showing  message my site

Answer (score 0):

Please see your directory structor carefully.According to url something is repeating into your url.

```
/var/www/humspm/data/www/humspm.com/gettext.php
```

Also see mkdir is only working with the directory path, not the URL or domain.
    You should have to point to your subdomain's absolute path, not the URL.

Comment: Hello Manoj Greetings, I do not have directory structure like /var/www

Comment: Cheers dear  :)
Please be careful about url and domain path.Both are different things.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error on a client's WordPress site:

```
(Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /var/www/humspm/data/www/humspm.com/gettext.php on line 17 CMD:EXIT)
```

I found that their `index.php` file was calling a file named `cache.php` on line 1.
`cache.php` contained obfuscated code that appears to have been attempting to use the invalid absolute path. The use of obfuscated code probably explains why you couldn't find any reference to that directory path in your code.

The actual file name may differ in your site, I'd recommend looking out for any unfamiliar php files in the same directory as your index.

Commenting out the line in `index.php` that called to this `cache.php` **fixed the issue** with the warning message.
However, the file itself appears to be malicious so I'm recommending that my client harden their security and scan for additional malware. You might want to do the same.